# How to read all the parquet files from s3 directory, with pandas?

Tags: pandas

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html), if I understand correctly, I should be able to give pandas a path to the root directory, and it will read all the parquet.

> A directory path could be: `file://localhost/path/to/tables` or `s3://bucket/partition_dir`.

But if I try to run -

```
pd.read_parquet(f"s3://my-bucket/data",
                columns=columns,
                storage_options=get_aws_creds_dict())
```

I'm getting `FileNotFoundError`.

What am I missing? How can I read all the parquet files as one DataFrame?

Comment: You're using "pd.read_parquet" correctly. Just looks like a wrong S3 path, check that's there's something in that location "aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/data/"